# passing a method pointer as a template parameter: why can't I use an inherited method here?

Tags: c++, templates

The following code (condensed from a larger program) does not compile with clang or gcc.

```
struct S1 {
  void m1() {}
};

template<typename B> struct S2 : B {
  void m2() {}
  void m3();
};

template<typename S, void (S::*m)()> void f1(S* o) {
  (o->*m)();
}

template<typename B> void S2<B>::m3() {
  f1<S2, &S2::m1>(this);
}

int main() {
  void (S2<S1>::*m)() = &S2<S1>::m1;
  S2<S1> o;
  o.m3();
}
```

Here is clang's error message:

```
bad.cc:15:3: error: no matching function for call to 'f1'
  f1<S2, &S2::m1>(this);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bad.cc:21:5: note: in instantiation of member function 'S2<S1>::m3' requested
      here
  o.m3();
    ^
bad.cc:10:43: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified
      argument for template parameter 'm'
template<typename S, void (S::*m)()> void f1(S* o) {
                                          ^
1 error generated.
```

This code compiles when I replace `m1` by `m2`. Clearly the compiler knows about `m1` (different message when I replace `m1` by `m4`), so why should a pointer to it be invalid in this context?

Comment: Why don't you just say `f1<S1, &S1::m1>(this);`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB Because `S1` is not the only possibility for `B`.

Comment: It does work with `B` instead of `S2`, which is useful to know, but it would be nice if I didn't have to assume that `m1` is defined in a base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, the type of m1 is `void(S1::*)(void)`, not `void(S2::*)(void)`. So fix it by leveraging the known base class name:

```
struct S1 {
    void m1() {}
};

template<typename B> struct S2 : B {
    void m2() {}
    void m3();
};

template<typename S, typename B, void (B::*m)(void)> void f1(S* o) {
    (o->*m)();
}

template<typename B> void S2<B>::m3() {
    f1<S2, B, &B::m1>(this);
}

int main() {
    S2<S1> o;
    o.m3();
}
```

Of course this doesn't (yet) scale to methods defined in indirect base classes, but with a bit of TMP it can be done (will see if I can post that while the intermission of Going Native 2012 lasts :))

The more 'flexible' approach would be:

```
template<typename B, typename MF> void f1(B* o, MF mfp) {
    (o->*mfp)();
}

template<typename B> void S2<B>::m3() {
    f1(this, &B::m1);
}
```

You could/should use typetraits to ensure that `S2<B>&` is convertible to a `B&` if the class layout doesn't already explicitly guarantee that, as in your current example.

Comment: _type of `m1` is `void(S1::*)(void)`_ What? `S2<S1>` inherits that method.

Comment: Indeed! It inherits `S1::m1`, not `S2::m1`, since the latter doesn't exist. Inheriting `S1::m1` does _not_ magically define a new function `S2::m1`. Consider what the linker looks for when asked for the address? Perhaps you are confused with virtual functions?

Comment: Let me refine that: the type of `m1` is a subtype of `void(S2::*)()`. Why should there be an error?

Comment: Also, if `S2` were to multiply inherit some fields stored before `S1`, I would expect one possible implementation strategy would be for the compiler to create a new address (http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/c++/3802.html).

Comment: @notagain: re the second: pointer-to-member functions aren't pointers, and they very definitely are *not* addresses. (Perhaps under the covers they are implemented as a type identification + an address OR offset into a vtable;). Main point, `m1 is a subtype of void(S2::*)()` is a false claim

Comment: So why isn't the first line of `main` an error, then? Your explanation doesn't make sense.

Comment: @notagain: that is a good point. The difference appears to be that the template argument requires a compiletime constant expression (constexpr), whereas the first line of main doesn't.

Comment: Okay, that checks out. Chalk it up to more standards lunacy.

Comment: @notagain: Cheers; I hope the simpler alternative I showed helps, regardless of the - admittedly - confusing business with ptr-to-memfuns (which, in fact, never have been 'fun')